# How will Shiva destroy the universe?

Tags: shiva

Shiva is said to have been the destroyer whereas Vishnu is the preserver and Brahma is the creator. How will Shiva destroy the universe?

Comment: He uses what is called the Maha Pashupatastra.

Comment: do you have any source that supports that he will destroy it by pashupatastra.If yes,then please include that source also.